# Fetching data while app in background state

Tags: iphone, xcode, background, core-location

I  want the following to implement in my app:

1. mobile app has to download a list of locations periodically [web service] , in background [even if the application is not running] .
2. Have to compare the user's current location with those downloaded locations each time.[in background]
3. Have to alert the user if he is near that location.[push notification]

Can we implement these things [is it possible to call webservice in background]while app is not active ? I have searched a lot and now assuming that calling webservice while app is not in active state is not possible. Kindly confirm.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the 3 task i.e to alert the user using push notification.
As in the inactive state, your app can only receive push notification.

You cannot call a webService.

Answer (score 1):

1: it is impossible to do action if the app is not running 
2: it is possible, you can find example for this purpose from iOS SDK document library 
3: the app have to running and detect current location real time... when near POI then notify user, about APNS, the same way... the app have to post the current location to back end web server, the web server need detect whether near POI, if yes... send notification via APNS...

hope above helpfully

Comment: So i cannot call webservice in background...but it is possible to compare users location with the downloaded locations...I want to download locations while app is active and to save those locations. am i correct? can i proceed like this? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: it is possible to get current location data while app in inactivate (still in running ) mode , so the app can detect whether near a POI which was predefined in the app